# Camera rotation in Blender

Tags: python, camera, transforms

I'm trying to export camera from Rhino, as soon as the OBJ does not have camera information in it what I'm doing is just copy-paste the camera coordinates and rotation.

With the rotation I have troubles. So what I'm doing is I measure the angle between the Z axis and the camera direction in the ZX plane and ZY plane projection (the camera pointing down). That works only for the small angles, the bigger angle the bigger mistake. I do not touch the third camera coordinate because it is just aligned with the x coordinate.

I will be very appreciated for the help

Answer (score 1):

So, the answer is. Instead of measuring the angles between camera direction and axis I should measure the angles between axes and the local axes of the plain aligned with the camera.